# App engine not syncing index after vacuum

Tags: google-app-engine

I have uploaded my application with some indexs (only 5). But it was taking long time to build, I waited 2 days but it was still in "Building" state. After googling I found few solutions, one was vacuum all the index and then redeploy indexs. I did vacuum indexs (by emptying my index.yaml file and then running vacuum command). I re-deployed indexes using update index command but in admin console it saying "You have not created indexes for this application.".

I was wondering did anyone face this problem, is there anything I can do to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be an issue where building indexes would become stuck and need a Googler to un-stick them.

Submit a production issue with your app-id (choose "production" from the drop down)

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list